# Invalid URL Python urllib.request.urlopen

Tags: python

I am downloading pdf from a link, the link that is correct, but when it comes to accessing me throws an exception

**Error**

```
raise InvalidURL(f"URL can't contain control characters. {url!r} "
http.client.InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/pnp/archivos/portal/doc/1305doc_NP 3215 DESTRUYEN POZA DE MACERACI%C3%93N Y GRAN CANTIDADDE INSUMOS QU%C3%8DMICOS.pdf' (found at least ' ')
```

**Code**

```
import unittest
from urlunshort3 import UrlUnshortener
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib.request

def download_file2(download_url):
   print(download_url)
   url = download_url
   response =  urllib.request.urlopen(url)
   data = response.read()
   with open('C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/files/example.pdf', 'wb') as archivo:
       archivo.write(data)
   with open('C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/files/example.pdf', 'r') as archivo:
       print("True")

download_file2(UrlUnshortener().resolve_short("http://bit" + ".ly/31wMeIN"))
```

Comment: Please, don't use any screenshot of a code to ask a question

Comment: @Andra Thanks for the editing, I really didn't want to add a picture

Comment: All the spaces should be URL encoded in order to  be processed. That's what the error message is telling. Even if you were provided the URL, a browser executes this parsing and so should your code. If the answer by @Peri did not help, check again and edit your question with all relevant info

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def download_file2(download_url):
 print(download_url)
 url = urllib.parse.quote(download_url)
 response =  urllib.request.urlopen(url)
 data = response.read()
 with open('C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/files/examle.pdf', 'wb') as archivo:
  archivo.write(data)
 with open('C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/files/example.pdf', 'r') as archivo:
  print("True")
```

Also try `urllib.parse.quote_plus()` if your url contains spaces to change them to plus signs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but now I receive another similar error, and added an example to my question, first I decode a shortener in the original link and that same deal I want to download it

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use wget

download from : https://pypi.org/project/wget/

```
import wget
wget.download(url)
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, but for some link it works and for others it doesn't, for example it doesn't work: wget.download (UrlUnshortener (). resolve_short ( "https://bit" + ".ly/2P1LxF8"))

Comment: apparently the link you provide as an example has accents, maybe the problem

Comment: The pypi link I shared is to get wget module.  Try downloading an image or pdf or any file using it in place of url and it should work